# How to add a new column to an existing table in TypeOrm using Migrations

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

I have a node typescript typeorm app.

I'm trying to stay with `syncronize: false` since i've read that in production it's safer to have it false or it may cause loss of data.. Anyway...

I have some entities that were created by migrations (and in DBeaver everything was ok), but i've noticed that i forgot to add a column in a specific table.
Now i saw that to add a column to that table i should create a new migration called for example "AddNewColumnToTable" with queryRunned.AddColumn etc...

Everything is ok since i try to run that migration to create that new column.

I tried `npx typeorm migration:run`  but i get errors like "cannot use import statement outside a module.
I tried to run all the migrations but nothing changes.. it says no migrations are in pending
(obviously i also runned npm run build before running those commands)

Any help would be delightfull! Thanks!

Comment: Can you share more about the name of the file as well as the code?

Answer (score 0):

Ok my whole problems where due to my appDataSource where i load all the FakeName.migration.ts and my file was missing of that .migration part in the fileName, so it wasn't detected as a migration and it wouldnt start